# How to rename a folder created during build process? It keep going back to the original name

Tags: java, eclipse, build

Here's exactly what I did:

1. Download jMetal 5.6 and extracted files under the workspace directory for Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0). Then it created a directory called jMetal-master
2. From the File menu, I used the command for creating a new project from existing directory, for which I pointed to the jMetal-master directory
   When I click on the finish button on the create new project wizard, it displayed the project jMetal-master on the Package Explorer console and on the bottom part of the developer screen it gave one error message that reads:
   The project was not built due to "A resource exists with a different case: '/jMetal-master/bin/org/uma/jmetal/qualityIndicator'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent   jMetal-master

I believe this error has something to do with the "bin" directory which was created during project creation process. I tried to rename the qualityIndicator folder in the bin folder, but it does not let me to rename the directory.

Again, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: everywhere in the code the package name reads: org.uma.jmetal.qualityindicator;
however, there is an interrface declaration in which qualityindicator is written as QualityIndicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a **case-insensitive file system** (e. g. 
generally on Windows or [using HFS+ on macOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/22297)) **you cannot compile** the **jMeter** modules *jmetal-core* and *jmetal-exec* **into the same output folder** (in your case `/jMetal-master/bin`), because two different package names are used which differ only in uppercase and lowercase:

- [`org.uma.jmetal.qualityindicator`](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetal/blob/master/jmetal-core/src/main/java/org/uma/jmetal/qualityindicator/QualityIndicator.java#L1) (with lower-case `i`)
- [`org.uma.jmetal.qualityIndicator`](https://github.com/jMetal/jMetal/blob/master/jmetal-exec/src/main/java/org/uma/jmetal/qualityIndicator/CommandLineIndicatorRunner.java#L1) (with upper-case `I`)

**Solution:**

Use separate output folders or in the package name of `org.uma.jmetal.qualityIndicator.CommandLineIndicatorRunner` replace the upper-case `I` with a lower-case `i`.

Comment: I tried it in on a Mac, and still the problem persists. During the create new project wizard on Eclipse, I selected the option "Allow output folders for source folders" and that seems to resolve the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are case-insensitive file systems on macOS, too. Thanks for the hint. I have corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Instead of using File/New/Java Project, I used File/Open Projects from File System. No more error messages.

Comment: it still does not compile though.